# Laravel Events and Listerners and Job queues are same

Tags: php, laravel

If I use jobs, my code will run more quickly and in the background; but, if I use events and listeners, my code will take time-consuming as well as actual code time. I need to grasp the distinction between laravel jobs and events and listeners.

I tried events and jobs. Both tasks are completed more quickly and quietly. But events time just like actual code, thus I need to understand the distinction between jobs and events.

Comment: As you pointed yourself, "jobs" will run in the background, while use of event/listener will wait for finish and then allow response to be sent back (i.e. to the browser). So if jobs/queue is involved, clicking something on page doesn't wait that process to finish. On other hand, listener code has to finish to allow application to continue - finish request and send response back.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, @Tpojka. We use events and listeners, like you indicated above, as a simple code separator and reusability. functionality??

Comment: It is correct assumption. Maintenance of code is way easier, framework counts on it you'd use that advantage (instead putting everything in controller, service etc.). Also, there are other functionalities ready in event class, like broadcasting if used.